# Method Classpath() not found. Enabling SafeArgs in app

Tags: android, gradle, android-safe-args

Currently going through Android Developers "Build Your First Android App in Kotlin" tutorial. Attempting to enable safe args. Running into the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCDfX.png)
How should I fix this?

So far I have added the id `androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin` to the app level build.gradle file and in the project level build.gradle file I've added the following code to the dependencies block:

```
def nav_version = "2.5.3"
classpath ("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
```

Comment: Which exact tutorial are you following? The only one by that name that I found [doesn't have parentheses after the word classpath](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin#8).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin#0
That's the tutorial. Parenthesis was something I tried in my last attempt. Regardless of whether I include them or not I still run into the same error.

Comment: Can you include your entire `build.gradle` file with where you've added those lines?